# Convert string categorical data in data frame to Numeric data

Tags: r, dataframe, neural-network, data-conversion

I have the following  values (800) in my data frame

```
cat1 <- c("bi", "bt", "ch", "fs", "hc", "lh", "mo", "ms", "nn", "ro", "sc", "si", "so", "ti", "ww", "dt", "3et", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "aam", "aao", "ac", "acs", "aeo", "aeq", "afm", "aic", "aio", "akq", "am", "am", "am", "am", "amc", "amc", "aoq", "aoq", "aot", "apm", "apo", "apo", "aqf", "ass", "ata", "ata", "atc", "atf", "atq", "atr", "aun", "bae", "baf", "bai", "bcm", "bcs", "bea", "bee", "bef", "bem", "bem", "bem", "bem", "bem", "beo", "beo", "beq", "beq", "beq", "bhm", "bkr", "bm", "bm", "bme", "bmm", "bmm", "bmo", "bmq", "bmq", "brm", "brm", "brq", "bsm", "bsm", "bsm", "bsm", "bso", "bta", "bwa", "clm", "dd", "dm", "ne", "pp", "pv", "rt", "se", "sw")
```

I want to replace all string values with numeric values so that I can feed them in a neural network eg I want all "am" to be replaced with 5 or 0.5 and all "bem" to be replaced with 7 or 0.7 means according to some logic.
Tried many things but able to achieve anything

Comment: Not clear though.  There are many values and not sure how all of them should be replaced.  If you want tl convert to numeric, one option is `as.integer(factor(data9$cat1))` or `match(data9$cat1, unique(data9$cat1))`

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(cat1))`

Comment: both of them worked :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you have know what is the replacement rule, you can establish a dictionary and using named variables for look up.

For instance,

```
cat1 <- c("bem","am","am","bem","am")
dict <- `names<-`(c(7,5),c("bem","am"))
res <- dict[cat1]
```

and you will get

```
> res
bem  am  am bem  am 
  7   5   5   7   5
```

Comment: But What if I have 800 unique values in my data frame

Comment: @MeenakshiGarg but with 800 unique values, do you know what they are mapped from?

Comment: @MeenakshiGarg then you can establish a one-to-one mapping from the word to the number

Comment: @MeenakshiGarg if I understand your purpose correctly, you have 800 unique words to be replaced by 800 unique numbers, am I right? But do you know which word is for which number? If you don't the corresponding replacement, you cannot do it for sure. In your example, you know "am" to be replaced with 5  and all "bem" to be replaced with 7, but you should also know  what should be the replacements for "bi", "bt", "ch", "fs", and others.